# Куда выводить сообщения?

Tags: java, javafx

Задача такая , нужно выводить сообщение Отправителя и Принимателя . Помимо сообщений будет время отправки и статутс отправки , а так же изображение отправителя .Что лучше для этого подойдет ListView или TextArea

Comment: По описанным - скорее всего ListView в detailed режиме - как минимум 3 колонки (текст, дата, аватарка отправителя).
Если уже это не понравится, тогда думать о чём-то более сложном...

Comment: @Netch Можно поподробней про этот режим detailed или ссылку , я к сожалению не нашел ничего )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны использовать кастомный `ListView`. Как такой реализовать, можете просмотреть на данном [ресурсе](http://fxexperience.com/2012/05/listview-custom-cell-factories-and-context-menus/).

```
Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T> wrappedCellFactory = ...; 

Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T> cellFactory = new Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>() {
    @Override public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> listView) {
        ListCell<T> cell = wrappedCellFactory  == null ? new DefaultListCell<T>() : wrappedCellFactory.call(listView);
        cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        return cell;
    }
};

ListView<T> listView = new ListView<T>();
listView.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

Далее:

```
public class DefaultListCell<T> extends ListCell<T> {
    @Override public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else if (item instanceof Node) {
            setText(null);
            Node currentNode = getGraphic();
            Node newNode = (Node) item;
            if (currentNode == null || ! currentNode.equals(newNode)) {
                setGraphic(newNode);
            }
        } else {
            setText(item == null ? "null" : item.toString());
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Далее:

```
public class ContextMenuListCell<T> extends ListCell<T> {

    public static <T> Callback<ListView<T>,ListCell<T>> forListView(ContextMenu contextMenu) {
        return forListView(contextMenu, null);
    }

    public static <T> Callback<ListView<T>,ListCell<T>> forListView(final ContextMenu contextMenu, final Callback<ListView<T>,ListCell<T>> cellFactory) {
        return new Callback<ListView<T>,ListCell<T>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> listView) {
                ListCell<T> cell = cellFactory == null ? new DefaultListCell<T>() : cellFactory.call(listView);
                cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                return cell;
            }
        };
    }

    public ContextMenuListCell(ContextMenu contextMenu) {
        setContextMenu(contextMenu);
    }
}
```

И наконец:

```
MenuItem helloWorld = new MenuItem("Hello World!");
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(helloWorld);

listView.setCellFactory(ContextMenuListCell.<Person>forListView(contextMenu));

listView.setCellFactory(ContextMenuListCell.<Person>forListView(contextMenu, customCellFactory));
```